# how to add docker to a ubuntu 14 qcow2 image

Tags: docker, openstack, kvm, fedora20

I have a Ubuntu 14 .qcow2 cloud image, which I'm running with Fedora 20 KVM and OpenStack. I would like to add / install docker to that image and "re-save" is as a base image, so any VMs created from it would have docker pre-installed.
How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm developing on a Mac, using Parallels, I found these instructions, which worked for me:

http://vanappdeveloper.com/2013/07/04/converting-parallels-vm-to-linux-kvm/

Basically, this involves installing Ubuntu under Parallels, installing docker on the freshly installed Ubuntu OS, navigating over to the actual .hds file (make sure you grab the one with non-zero size!), copying that file over to the machine running qemu, and doing the emu conversion. By following these instructions, I was able to upload the resulting .qcow2 image file to my OpenStack instance, and launch a couple of VMs, which where pre-configured with docker.